# How to give mutiple color in one cell if it contains formulas in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell with formula

```
="Average:"& AVERAGE(C2,C6)& "Items:"& SUM(C2,C6)
```

I need the "Average" as Red color in that cell. Remaining in black color

Comment: You can't. You'd have to replace the formula with values, or just use two cells.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with a VBA solution, you will still have to copy/paste-special->values since you can't color only certain characters of a cell if that cell is a formula.

To wrap up the manual steps into a VBA subroutine we will have to:

1. Copy the value from the formula and paste it in a new cell.
2. Determine where the text "Item:" starts and how many characters it contains
3. Paint the characters in the value'd cell the colors required.

(Assuming your formula is D1) It would look like:

```
Sub avgSumColor()
    Dim rngFormulaCell As Range, rngValueCell As Range
    Dim itemStart As Integer, itemLength As Integer

    'Set the cell with the formula and the cell where we'll put the value
    Set rngFormulaCell = Sheet1.Range("D1")
    Set rngValueCell = Sheet1.Range("D2")

    'Copy/Paste special (just set the value of the valuecell to the value of the formulacell)
    rngValueCell.Value = rngFormulaCell.Value

    'Figure out where "Item:<number>" starts and
    '   how many characters long it is
    itemStart = InStr(1, rngValueCell.Value, "Items")
    itemLength = Len(rngValueCell.Value) + 1 - itemStart

    'set the first bit up to the text "Item:<number>" to red
    rngValueCell.Characters(1, itemStart).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    'set the last bit containing "Item:<number>" to black
    rngValueCell.Characters(itemStart, itemLength).Font.Color = RGB(1, 1, 1)
End Sub
```